# Angular: Save file with SaveAs file dialog

Tags: angular

All I need is to save blob object to file with opening SaveAs file dialog, so the user is able to change file name before saving it.

Is there any library/module that allows me to do it in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

When downloading a file in the browser, the downloaded file will go to your specified system folder (e.g Download). Triggering system "Save As" modal is not possible from the browser.

However we could fake the modal inside the angular App where user could rename the file and then proceed to download it.

Would recommend ngx-filesaver https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver for saving the file.

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { FileSaverService } from 'ngx-filesaver';

export interface DialogData {
  animal: string;
  name: string;
}

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {
  file: File = {
    name: 'example.png',
    blob: 'iVBORw0KGg',
  };

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {
        name: this.file.name,
        blob: this.file.blob,
      },
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
  file: any;
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    private _FileSaverService: FileSaverService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData
  ) {
    this.file = data;
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  onSaveAs() {
    const fileName = this.file.name;
    const fileType = this._FileSaverService.genType(fileName);
    const txtBlob = new Blob([this.file.blob], { type: fileType });
    this._FileSaverService.save(txtBlob, fileName);
  }
}

export interface File {
  name: string;
  blob: string;
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7t4bzs-87lray?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. So the conclusion is there is no library for Angular like the previous version of https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js was for AngularJS (now I'm looking at that the oldest version has a number 1.2.0, but in our AngularJS project there is even older version 1.1.2xxx)? Everything what user had to do was to call ```$window.saveAs(blob, fileName);``` and that was it. Then Save as dialog opened etc.

Comment: Oh of course that's possible, you just need to setup your functions as such. Move the dialogs to a dialog service and for example, call openDialog and pass file as param.

Comment: @JoosepParts I am getting this error (It appears that we don't support this file format) after saving the image from slackblitz.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I tried to use the function saveAs from FileSaver.js library in Angular project and probably the manipulation with files is simply different, because the same piece of code, which opens a save dialog in AngularJS, straightforward downloads the file in Angular...